# Distributing autotool metafiles

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake

`AM_MAINTAINER_MODE` has been criticized, and I believe the main objection is that it leads to incorrect builds if dependencies on meta-files are not detected.  Also, it is often argued that generated files do not belong in version control systems (I agree with that position).  I currently believe that if `configure` does not belong in the vcs, then `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` do not belong in the tarball.  To that end, I've written a simple script to clean certain targets out of Makefile.in and added the following target to the top-level Makefile.am:

```
dist-hook:
    @rm $(distdir)/configure.ac
    @rm $(distdir)/aclocal.m4
    @find $(distdir) -name Makefile.am -exec rm {} \;
    @find $(distdir) -name Makefile.in -exec $(top_srcdir)/clean-Makefile {} \;
```

This solution sidesteps the problematic issues that derive from `AM_MAINTAINER_MODE` because there are no meta-files to be modified.

It strikes me that one of the biggest failings of autoconf is the misperception that every project built using it has a dependency on autoconf (this is not an autoconf failing, but a failing of marketing/education), and this misperception is largely the result of tarballs containing meta-files.

Question:  Is there a better way to accomplish the desired goal of creating a tarball that does not contain autotool metafiles?  (The question of whether that goal is merely 'arguably undesirable' or 'truly evil' is too open for this forum!)

Comment: I think this is not a goot idea. When I download a source tarball, I want ALL sources, including the complete build system.

Comment: @Rudi.  You get the complete build system!  The autotool metafiles are not part of the build system; they are merely used to create the build system.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I understand why you want to do this.  It would be (somewhat) easier for most package users if those files were absent.  But as the autotools are a GNU product, designed to make GPL distributions easier including compliance with their own license (the "corresponding source" in GPL3).  If someone wants to "modify the work" by adding translation units and other stuff, they are going to need configure.ac and Makefile.am.

Comment: One does not use autotools to tweak how it does things.  It is a cranky old man: do it the cranky old man way.

Comment: The tarball is not the work, it is merely a derivative of the work.  The original work is that which is contained in the vcs.  The tarball is the distribution, the vcs contains the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way to do this, but Automake wouldn't support it even if there was.

Automake's primary goal is to implement the GNU coding standards regarding Makefiles.  And, it is a tenet of GNU that users should be given the primary sources to hack on -- this is a requirement of the GPL.

Shipping the derived files but not the sources is against this idea.

I think your theory here is misguided.  Users benefit from having the source.  For example, it's reasonably common to have to hack the configury or build scripts; and this is much simpler with the source code.

Comment: For a few months, I experimented with release tarballs that had the autotool meta files removed but included a complete git repository to satisfy the condition of including all sources. I would still get emails from devs complaining about build errors.   The "fix" included lowering the version number specified in AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE. I had hoped that requiring the dev to understand the source well enough the make them check things out from the git repo would reduce that sort of issue. Next best solution is for the major distros to stop installing automake! Make the dev install the tools in $HOME!